# Why is the size of a page table entry determined only by main memory size?

Tags: memory, operating-system

Excluding the valid, dirty and reference bits, considering only actual "mapping" from virtual address space to physical address space, why is it said that the size of a page table entry is determined by the number of bits required to reference a page from the main memory (Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770650/3684931)

My argument is that since a physical address can be in secondary storage too (which is the point of using virtual memory), the size of a page table entry should simply be equal to the number of bits to required to reference any page among all the pages in the virtual memory.

**To give an example**, if virtual address space is addressable by 64 bits,  main memory is addressable by 48 bits and page size is 16KB (addressable by 14 bits), a page table should map (64 - 14) 50 bit addresses to (64 - 14) 50 bit addresses and not (48 - 14) 34 bit addresses.

It *could* map to 34 bit addresses if the page exists in main memory, but otherwise, the upperbound should be 50 bits which should be considered while calculating the size of a page table.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page table entries are sized to support the virtual address size and the maximum amount of physical memory supported.  They are **not** sized based on any aspect of the secondary storage.

In your example, the page table has to support mapping `2^50` virtual pages to a possible `2^34` physical pages.  Thus a page table entry will use 34 bits to hold the physical page number.

If a page is not present in memory, and it was previously paged out to secondary storage, then a data structure (like a hash table) can be used to locate where in the paging file the page is located.  You don't need to use the page table structure to do this.

Comment: Thanks. So are programs written assuming they will get to use `2^64` bytes (virtual memory) or `2^48` bytes (main memory size) to themselves? In the former case, I don't understand why a page table entry should not map to secondary storage (why would that be delegated to a separate hash table?). In the latter case, why should there be `2^50` entries in the page table when the program can possibly address only `2^34` pages.

Comment: Programs are written assuming they get to use 2^64 bytes (assuming the compiler, OS and CPU all support 64 bit bit addresses).   You want to keep the size of PTEs small so the PTE cache (TLB) can be small.   Putting enough information in the PTE so that you can find the page on backing store could make the PTE bigger for no gain in performance.

Comment: @SachinHosmani - if my answer works for you please approve it.  If not, please let me know why it isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly is this hash table you mentioned in your answer called? If a page doesn't exist in memory, what will the page table entry for it be? It can't be a memory location obviously. It somehow has to point at this hash table. How does the hash table lookup happen?

Comment: The page table entry will have the `present`/`valid` bit off.   All other parts of the PTE are invalid.   The kernel or swap process needs to be able to map a process id and a page number to where that page is found in the backing store.  This can be in a regular file for a page containing the code for the process, or it can be in the swap file for the process's data.   This is the kind of information you don't want to force into the PTE.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a page table must account for:
1. Control bits
2. Access restriction bits
3. The page size
4. The number of bits requires to access the required number of pages.

The page table entries correspond to the virtual memory. The number of entries times the page size is the virtual address size.

The entries themselves only need to address physical memory.

Comment: right, so with my example, what is the size of each entry in the page table **considering only** bits required to reference a page? Is my upperbound of 50 bits correct?